# loading another nib into a viewController

Tags: iphone, ios, xib, nib

I have a ViewController that includes its own .nib file, I am wanting to load another .nib into this ViewController that will be a menu of sorts... however I am just not sure how to do this and was hoping for some help.

Before I show you the code I will explaine what I have done.

- I have a UIViewController with a Nib that is my main view.
- I have created another nib which is going to be a menu that appears as a subview to the main view
- I have changed this nibs class to the UIViewController of the main view so that it can see all of the same IBActions and outlets.
- I have then run the code below trying to load the seperate nib as a subview however when I run it the subview of the other nib is not showing up....

  ```
      jumpBarPortraitNib = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 50.0, 320.0, 367.0)];



      // add jumpbar container to view
      [self.view insertSubview:jumpBarPortraitNib belowSubview:actionTabBar];
  ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's clearly some confusion here.

A nib is merely an archive that contains(*) objects, including (usually) one or more view objects (`UIView` in your case).  You don't "load a nib as a subview."  You instantiate the nib, potentially handing it to a `UIViewController` to own and manage it, and add a view referenced within the nib to your view hierarchy.

All you have done with your first line of code is create a generic `UIView` instance with a given frame size and insert it into whatever [self view] is.  There is *nothing* in what you wrote that actually references a nib, even though you misnamed your view as a nib.

For what you are doing, I would probably go one of two routes:

1. Add the view as a separate top-level view in your original nib, and connect it to an `IBOutlet`.  You can then display the menu easily from within the common `UIViewController` instance you have set as the nib's File Owner.
2. Have a separate `UIViewController` instance that will just manage the menu view, and which you will use to instantiate the nib's contents using `-initWithNibName:` as @Aaron mentioned.  (Note that you shouldn't need to set the frame externally; the frame will be archived in the nib as a property of the view.)

*: Not really, but you can think of it this way.

Comment: okay from what you have said I am trying to achieve what you have outlined in option 1.. I have set up a IBOutlet UIView and done the right click drag to the menu view (in Interface builder) but its not displaying with that code.. what do you think I have missed?

Comment: Good answer.  If you're just getting started with this type of programming you should read [this article](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/05/understanding-model-view-controller.html) which helped me out a ton with the basic concepts when I was starting.

Comment: @HurkNburkS OK, suppose you named your property/outlet "menuView."  Then you could do something as simple as `[[self view] addSubview:[self menuView]]`.

Comment: just realized **Add the view as a separate top-level view in your original nib,** so I am now taking the IB stuff I have done in the other nib and am adding it to the mainViewController nib.. will see how it goes.

Comment: okay thanks Conrad just saw your second response am about to give it ago.

Comment: weird.. not sure why but when I took out the ** jumpBarPortraitNib = [[UIView alloc] init];** of that new view it started showing ;)

Comment: @HurkNburkS Was your outlet called jumpBarPortraitNib by any chance?

Comment: @HurkNburkS It's a bit complicated, but you probably did a plain `@synthesize` for it, which creates a backing ivar of the same name.  Then when you instantiated the generic `UIView` with that name, you clobbered the instance-scoped ivar of the same name with a locally declared copy.  Removing that line fixed the ivar scope.  But you shouldn't use ivars directly - that's why I wrote `[self menuView]` instead of just `menuView`.

Comment: right I get you, How should have I handled the @synthesize then?

Comment: @HurkNburkS Well, don't call the outlet a nib (because it isn't), and use something like `@synthesize menuView = _menuView` - and make sure to use the accessor method `[self menuView]` instead of direct access.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use initWithNibName, and then set the frame on the following line:

```
UIViewController * jumpVC = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"jumpBarPortrait" bundle:nil];
jumpVC.view.frame = //your frame
```

Comment: Or, if you subclassed `UIViewController`, replace that with your custom class (like `MyAwesomeViewController`).

Comment: but the other nib dose not have a UIViewController.... this is what I am abit confused by...

Comment: @HurkNburkS You can optionally create another UIViewController subclass to manage your menu.  This has some theoretical advantages in the form of modularization.  Please see my response.

Comment: Every View has a View Controller.  That's how you tell it what to do when you press a button, etc.